# Loop through custom object's properties

Tags: json, swift

I have a JSON response with a structure like this:

```
{
    "id": {
        "sub_key1": "sub_value1",
        "sub_key2": "sub_value2",
        "sub_key3": "sub_value3",
        "used": false
    },
    "key1": {
        "sub_key1": "sub_value1",
        "sub_key2": "sub_value2",
        "sub_key3": "sub_value3",
        "used": true
    },
    "key2": {
        "sub_key1": "sub_value1",
        "sub_key2": "sub_value2",
        "sub_key3": "sub_value3",
        "used": false
    },
    "key3": {
        "sub_key1": "sub_value1",
        "sub_key2": "sub_value2",
        "sub_key3": "sub_value3",
        "used": true
    },
    "key4": {
        "sub_key1": "sub_value1",
        "sub_key2": "sub_value2",
        "sub_key3": "sub_value3",
        "used": false
    },
    "key5": {
        "sub_key1": "sub_value1",
        "sub_key2": "sub_value2",
        "sub_key3": "sub_value3",
        "used": true
    }
}
```

I have created Swift parent and child structs for it like this:

Parent:

```
struct Parent: Codable {
    let id: Child?
    let key1: Child?
    let key2: Child?
    let key3: Child?
    let key4: Child?
    let key5: Child?
}
```

Child:

```
struct Child: Codable {
    let sub_key1: String?
    let sub_key2: String?
    let sub_key3: String?
    let used: Bool?
}
```

Now, only some of the Child objects are being used, depending on the 'used' property, and I would like to filter out the unused Child objects. I thought about using the [map](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map) method, but that only works for arrays.

Any ideas on how I could go about solving this problem?

Comment: Can you add an example with input and output?

Comment: I'd recommend storing `Child` objects 1-5 in an `Array` or `Dictionary` depending on whether they should have a non-contiguous/non-integer key, then you can simply use `filter` (`map` is not what you are looking for) to only keep the ones whose `used` property is `true`. In most cases when you are creating several properties of the same type and you come up with a numbered naming for the properties, it is a sign that those properties should be stored in a collection data structure (`Array` for instance) rather than as individual properties.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts David, but the problem is I can't use an Array or Dictionary because the JSON is in object format, not array format. Perhaps I am not understanding your suggestion fully?

Comment: this json from where are you getting? from a json file inthe project or from any API call?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with storing `Parent` as this:

```swift
struct Parent {
    let children: [String: Child]
}
```

This will allow you to filter the children using `parent.children.values.filter` and add some dynamism to the keys.

**As a side note:**

**Swift 4.2** will allow you to have dynamic calls. This means that you could implement:

```swift
extension Parent {
    subscript(dynamicMember member: String) -> Child? {
        get {
            return children[member]
        }
        set {
            children[member] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

which will in turn allow you to still call `parent.key1` or `parent.id` and not lose readability.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your JSON data to dictionary first. Then I take the values of that dictionary and create an array out of it. Then loop through each dictionary of that array and convert that into a Child object and save that in the child array(which is an array of child objects).

Then instead of map, we will use **filter** method to filter out the objects with used as true.

```
func fetchData() {

    let dataSourceURL = URL(string: "yourURL")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: dataSourceURL)
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    let task = URLSession(configuration: .default).dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!",
                                                message: "There was an error fetching json data.",
                                                preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
        alertController.addAction(okAction)

        if let data = data {
            do {
                let yourJSONAsDict =
                    try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data,
                                                               options: [],
                                                               format: nil) as! [String: Any]

                let valueArray = Array(yourJSONAsDict.values)
                var childArray = [Child]()
                for value in valueArray {
                    if let valueDict = value as? [String: Any] {
                        let childObj = Child(valueDict: valueDict)
                        childArray.append(childObj)
                    }
                }

                var filteredArray = childArray.filter{ ($0.used ?? false) }

                print(filteredArray)


            } catch {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }

        if error != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Here is the Child struct that I am using, for your reference

```
struct Child: Codable {
    let sub_key1: String?
    let sub_key2: String?
    let sub_key3: String?
    let used: Bool?

    init(valueDict: [String: Any]) {
        self.sub_key1 = valueDict["sub_key1"] as? String
        self.sub_key2 = valueDict["sub_key2"] as? String
        self.sub_key3 = valueDict["sub_key3"] as? String
        self.used = valueDict["used"] as? Bool
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am getting the JSON from a server, so I cannot change the format. Otherwise I would have gone with your approach.